# Error starting camel subsystem in Wildfly 8.2.0.Final

Tags: java, apache-camel, wildfly-8

I get the following exception in my standalone/log/server.log when I use the instructions in (http://blog.eisele.net/2014/12/wildfly-camel-subsystem-for-wildfly-integrates-javaee-getting-started.html) to use the Camel subsystem in Wildfly 8.2.0.Final.

The issue seems to be resolved in a later version of Camel (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7992). So I tried changing the org/apache/camel/core module to use camel-core-2.14.1.jar but I still see the same exception. Any pointers on how I can resolve this issue? I am eager to try out the Camel subsystem.

```
2014-12-23 14:35:09,950 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "wildfly-camel.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-camel.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-camel.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000143: Container lifecycle event method invoked outside of extension observer method invocation.
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerEvent.checkWithinObserverNotification(ContainerEvent.java:61)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.getAnnotatedType(ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:56)
at org.apache.camel.cdi.internal.CamelContextConfig.configure(CamelContextConfig.java:47)
at org.apache.camel.cdi.internal.CamelContextBean.configureCamelContext(CamelContextBean.java:131)
at org.apache.camel.cdi.internal.CamelExtension.startConsumeBeans(CamelExtension.java:231)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:90)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:271)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:258)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:237)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:174)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:133)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:107)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:439)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:93)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgarde the camel-cdi jar to 2.14.1 as well. Please make sure you are using the same version of camel jars.

Comment: Do you know if there will be a 2.0.0.CR2 or some future version of the wildfly-camel-patch (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/wildfly/camel/wildfly-camel-patch/) with this fix?

Comment: Maybe you can try to build the widfly-camel which uses camel 2.14.1 yourself. https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel